# Is $f(x)=e^x \cdot \cos(e^x)$ a tempered distribution?

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f(x)=e^x \cdot \cos(e^x)$. Define $$T_f(\varphi)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \cdot \varphi(x) \ .$$ 
I would like to know if $T_f$ defined with the formula above defines a tempered distribution (in the sense of the definition given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: The integral of $f(x):=e^x \cdot \cos(e^x)$ is $F(x):=\sin(e^x)$ and defines a function of "slow growth" for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
Deduce that the derivative is a tempered distribution (without being a function of slow growth itself).